# How to use Facebook graph API query correctly

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am a new comer .Someone suggested me that i will get a solution of my question from this site.So that's why i am posting my question in here.
When i used this facebook fql query:

http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+like_info+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id=723217944369470

Answer was:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "like_info": {
        "can_like": false,
        "like_count": 7,
        "user_likes": false
     }
  }
 ]
}
```

But when i used this facebook fql query:

http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+like_info+FROM+stream+WHERE+post_id=488253731301614

Answer was:

```
{
"data": [

     ]
}
```

Why?and how to query correctly to get a post's like info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In graph API, you can do something like this to get a post's likes:

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

You need to replace POST_ID and ACCESS_TOKEN with actual values.

You can use Graph API Explorer to generate an access_token

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  (don' forgot asking for sufficient permission to view the post in question).

Comment: This show's me full id and name who liked this post not the count.I need only "like_info/like_count".

Comment: To get the like_count, append "?summary=1" at the end of the Graph call

Comment: /POST_ID/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&summary=1

Comment: Bro you rocks.finally I've got my answer.But one more thing,can't i do this using fql query like above or some how else?Because it will help me a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I never use FQL. May be someone else has an answer for that. But you will love Graph API once you start using it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to write down a php code to call total_count of a post using GRAPH API?

Comment: You mean total comments on a post? Once you get the JSON response from facebook, look into the summary field: $count = response['summary']['total_count'];

Comment: Bro, if i use /POST_ID/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&summary=1 sometime it shows ("message": "Unsupported get request.","type": "GraphMethodException","code": 100).Why?

Comment: For me, this call always works given that the POST_ID and ACCESS_TOKEN are valid. Can you tell me some sample cases where it gives the above-mentioned error?

Comment: I've pasted this link (https://graph.facebook.com/488253731301614/likes?access_token=CAAD56VGoLlIBAKZCsRF12K5NXcglqEl1ygCkppnQTDtKwTF2LZAPYBnCFNHjMefZCXsbZAZCLKZBgKndZAj9rV0ZAeyZClpM4VA7KjhUhaSzL13VyAHUUejLdbRiVjZAHWiVUlL8Ws2uHwzdcKoRuGDrqiZAe2UkgonVtY6XMtFIp77K4S2cC1Cl8KTCSSC2ybioYAl6eQpauT2twZDZD) in firefox and just now too got the same error.

Comment: bro, I've waited last tow days for your help.Didn't you read my last comment?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reach you earlier. I have checked the above URL and its giving the same error to me. I saw this post is a picture of yours. What I would suggest is to use the graph API to first find all your albums (me/albums). In the albums list, find the one that has above photos. Once you find the ID of the album that hosts the photo, you can use {ALBUM_ID}/photos to find all photos inside it. This will also give you an ID of the post in question. Use that ID to make a call. If that still gives the same error, then its most likely some permission problem.

Comment: I don't know if this is legal to put contact information here, but you can visit my profile -> website. There you'll find contact information.